# group a table list by a column name (sample included)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have a table that i need to group into divs

```
rated | rater | team | score | subject
john    mike     TA     10      math
john    mike     TA     10      PE
john    jane     TA     9       math
john    jane     TA     9       PE
kim     lee      TB     5       math
kim     min      TB     2       math
```

i need it to look like

```
 TA
    john
     RATER    MATH  PE         
     mike      10   10
     jane      9     9
 TB
   kim
    RATER     MATH  PE
    lee        5
    min        2
```

In my view I'm just iterating these values from a LINQ with a

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I use telerik grids. For examples:http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/Grid/Grouping

Depending on the requirements that you have, you can sort the Model into multiple List<model> in the controller or anywhere in the code and then format your models on the view.

As Ryan said, we need more contexts here to be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to transpose the columns and rows.

Check out this method from this blog:
http://higherlogics.blogspot.com/2010/05/linq-transpose-extension-method.html

Here's the code sample:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Transpose<T>(
     this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
return from row in source
       from col in row.Select(
           (x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, T>(i, x))
       group col.Value by col.Key into c
       select c as IEnumerable<T>;
}
```